# How to get json array in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

This is  I want to achieve:

1. I want to get array [data][a] value 3

json data is

```
 {"result":"true","password_expired":"true","data":{"a":"3","b":"2"}}
```

```
var map : Map<String, Any> = HashMap()
map = Gson().fromJson(jsonData, map.javaClass)
Log.i("Login", map["result"].toString())
```

How can i handle in kotlin code?

I want output array [data][a] is 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use org.json for that array in kotlin

like this

```
val response_data = //your json array data
val json_obj = JSONObject(response_data)
val dataX = json_obj.getJSONObject("data")
val finalX = dataX.getString("a")

println("VALUE : $finalX")
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can I use for loop in json_obj.getJSONObject("data")

Key : a
VALUE : 3

Key : b
VALUE : 2

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your question and answer! To improve the quality of your content it might be helpful taking a look at how to post code https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . Also it seems, that this answer is actually another question to your question. I recommend you to just edit your question and put the information from this answer into your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to get value of a and b then there is no need for a loop
you can do it directly like this

```
val response_data = //your json array data
val json_obj = JSONObject(response_data)
val dataX = json_obj.getJSONObject("data")
val finalX = dataX.getString("a")
val finalY = dataX.getString("b")

println("VALUE : $finalX")
println("VALUE : $finalY")
```

Answer (score 0):

if a and b is random key in the data, next time maybe is c and d.

how can use for loop to show key and value?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: please create another question regarding that , ill answer there